# Is there a canonical pattern for implementing self-memorizing function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I need to implement a simple cache in JavaScript for storing results of ajax requests. I know that one of the way is to implement self-memorizing function. But is there some general pattern for this in JavaScript, without using any frameworks?

Comment: Memorising or memoising?

Comment: Good question! Aren't these concepts equal?

Comment: Memoising has a specific meaning in computer science, 'memorising' is a more general English word and doesn't have a specific computer science meaning.

Comment: Memoising is typically used in functional programming where pure functions are used and the result of the function doesn't change for a given input. If you are making a request and the result of the request does not change then you could argue that that is memoisation. If you are just caching a value which might change in the future, that's plain cache.

Comment: Then I would say that my case is a plain cache case, and it's more like just "memorising".

Comment: Ok. You should probably just use the word 'cache' in your question then, using the word 'memorising' might be unhelpful. Also, try setting cache headers on your HTTP response, the browser does come with a built-in cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var getAjax = (function(params){
    var cache = {};
    var paramsToURLKey = function(params){
        return paramsConvertedToString; // convert params object to string and use it as key for cache
    };
    getAjax = function  (params, callback) {
        var key = paramsToURLKey(params);
        var result = cache[key]; // try to read previous request results
        if (!result) {
            sendRealRequest(params, function(response){
                //request callback
                cache[key] = response;

                callback(response);
            })
        }
    }

})();
```